# Organise sorting in back-end using REST API

Tags: java, rest, sorting, spring-data

I need to organise multi-column sorting and I get parameters in the GET query like this: /api/v1/invoices?sort=-date,+amount
The name of the parameters doesn't exactly match the name of fields in the entity. But I need the name of entity fields to use spring data Sort class

```
new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, getSortFields())
```

What is the best approach of getting the names of entity fields? Only Map with key - query parameter and value - entity field name come to my mind.

Comment: That what comes to my mind as well. What's the problem with this obvious solution?

Comment: No problems. I just think that more elegant solution can exist